# PySpark: Creating RDD from List of Dataframes

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd

I'm unable to create a RDD from a list of pyspark dataframes, seen below:

```
l = [('Alice', 1)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(l)
m = [('bob', 2)]
df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(m)
df_list = [df, df2]
sc.parallelize(df_list)
```

The error I get is: 
`Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o85.__getnewargs__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getnewargs__([]) does not exist`

at the `parallelize` call.  It works with a simple list such as `[1,2,3]`, but when the elements of the list becomes a dataframe, it seems to fail...  Please advise.

I have a timeseries dataframe which can be grouped by the `id` of a column.  Since I need to do some computation on each of the timeseries data, my idea was to split the dataframe into multiple dataframes by `id` and make each of them an element in a list, so when I create the RDD from that list, I can do computation on the dataframes in parallel.

I'm using Spark 1.6.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This can work only if your data frames has the same schema.

```
df = df.unionAll(df2)
rdd = df.rdd()
```

Comment: Thanks, for my other dataframe, they do have the same schema, but still doesn't work. Also, what I'm trying to do is create a RDD from a list of dataframes. I want to parallelize the computation done on the dataframes.  It's different from making each row of the original dataframe into an element of the RDD, does that make sense?

Comment: well, DataFrame is already distributed structure and if you want to redistribute your data you have to convert your `DataFrame` to structure that parallelize can take: `df = sc.parallelize(df.collect()+df2.collect())`. I think in that case union is more efficient way though.

Comment: even though the `collect` did what I wanted,  I have millions of dataframes which I need to run some aggregation on each of them and it was taking too long to do.

Comment: what is the source for your dataframes?

Comment: it's a bunch of workout data in one big table, where each workout id has roughly 500 datapoints.  From a site called endomondo